# Allow user to fill only one of the fields not both | Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm creating an app like reddit where you can post videos and texts.

I want to let the user choose between video and image field but not both

**here is what I've done:**

```
class CreatePostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','video','image','text']
        widgets ={'title':forms.TextInput({'placeholder':'تیتر'}), 'text':forms.Textarea({'placeholder':'متن'})}    
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        text = cleaned_data.get("text")
        video = cleaned_data.get("video")
        if text is not None and video is not None:
            raise ValidationError('this action is not allowed', 'invalid')
```

this shows the `validationError` **but** even when the user only fills the video `fileField` and not the `texField` it still shows the `validationError`

**UPDATE**

I've changed `if text is not None and video is not None:`
to
`if text != '' and video is not None:`
and now it works.
I still don't know why `not None` didn't work for text.

Comment: Likely because these fields are not `blank=True` in the `Post` model, and thus have `required=True` in the `ModelForm`.

Comment: They are both `blank = True` and they don't have `required=True` in the `ModelForm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def make_decision(text = None,video=None):
    if text != '' and video != '':
        print('--------- Both are not possible for selection ---------')
    elif text != '':
        text = '--------- calling only text ---------'
        print(text)
    elif video != '':
        video = '--------- calling only video ---------'
        print(video)
    else:
        print('--------- Please select atleast one ---------')

# ------ Possibility for calling function (test cases) --------------
make_decision('','')   # raise_error = '--------- Both are not possible for selection ---------'
# make_decision('y','')  # '--------- calling only text ---------'
# make_decision('','y')  # '--------- calling only video ---------'
# make_decision('','') # '--------- Please select atleast one ----'
```

Comment: This was almost the answer but for some reason `!=''` for video doesn't work but for text it does! so I've changed it to `if text != ' ' and video is not None` . thank you so much for your answer I will update my question so everyone can see

Answer (score 0):

Use `required=False` instead of `blank = True`

```
class CreatePostForm(ModelForm):
    video = forms.FileField(required=False)
    image = forms.FileField(required=False)
    ...
```